# Recursive function to create a text edit

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, recursion

I have controls in my view. All objects have different width and height. I have an array of these objects. I need to write recursive function that will move to a new line my objects if they don't fit in the current line (something like in notepad or textedit).

I suppose we need to check current object from array in cycle and  if it fits to width we don't do any operations and if it does not fit to width of current view (line) we should to make recursion. am I right? And move our object to new line while we have object in array.

Comment: Why do you need recursion for this, it's just an array you're iterating?

Comment: yes I can just recalculation all what I need. In your opinion is it most simple way? thanks for response

Comment: I think so. Hopefully someone comes along with a better answer.

Comment: How your objects are represented? How are they associated with a line? What is a purpose of your taks - is it to learn about recursion or solve the actual problem? Please rephrase your last comment, it simply doesn't mean anything in English.

Comment: All my objects are labels. This is an actual problem. Labels are located in a view. A view has got width (for ecample 300 points). My labels also have got width and they are located in one line. But I need to make calculation that my objects move on new life if they does not fit to width of current line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (assuming all starts at 0.0):

```
    NSArray* your_elements = ... //your elements in an NSArray (labels, buttons any type of views)

    CGFloat currentX = 0.0;
    CGFloat currentY = 0.0;

    CGFloat maxX = 320.0;
    CGFloat lineHeight = 12.0;

    for (UIView* some_view in your_elements) {
        CGRect newframe = some_view.frame;
        newframe.origin.x = currentX;
        newframe.origin.y = currentY;

        currentX += newframe.size.width;
        some_view.frame = newframe;

        if (currentX>maxX) {
            currentX = 0.0;
            currentY += lineHeight;
        }
    }
```